# Using DjangoFullSerializers to serialize custom ManyToMany relations into JSON

Tags: django, json

I'm using [DjangoFullSerializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) to serialize this model (into JSON):

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    start_date = models.DateField(...)
    timeline = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
    complete = models.BooleanField(...)

    designers = models.ManyToManyField(Designer, through='ProgramAssignment')
    milestones = models.ManyToManyField(Milestone, through='ProgramMilestone')
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to serialize all of this information -- i.e. not just the first four fields but all the designer & milestone information linked to this program. I've also [applied a patch](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/issues/detail?id=4) which seems to be able to solve my problem, but I've tried many different values for the `relations` keyword argument, such as `'milestones'`, `'milestone_set'`, `'ProgramMilestones'`, `'ProgramMilestone_set'`, etc. and none of them have worked so far for me.

If anyone knows how to serialize the last two M2M fields (using DjangoFullSerializers or otherwise), please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. The problem was that I needed to be calling Program.objects.**select_related()** and then pass the keyword argument `relations=('programmilestone_set', 'programassignment_set',)`.

Comment: I did the same, but it didn't help me.